# Enable foreach on SortedList

Tags: c#

I have the following code which I am trying to make work with Foreach. I am playing with C# so very beginner but cannot seem to get the IEnumerable bit working?? Can someone please tell me how I can loop over my list property.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
namespace MyApplication
{

    class arrayLess : IEnumerable {

        SortedList<string,dynamic> list = new SortedList<string,dynamic>();

        // Will need to update global list of array_values
        // This will be a proper array
        public void add(dynamic key,dynamic val){
            list[key.ToString()] = val;
        }

        // Could be int in which case need a list that isn't a sortedList?
        public dynamic get(dynamic key){
            return list[key.ToString()];
        }

        IEnumerator<string> IEnumerable<string>.GetEnumerator(){
            Console.WriteLine("HERE");
            return this.list.GetEnumerator();
        }

        IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator(){
            return this.list.GetEnumerator();
        }   
    }

    class launcher {
        static void Main(string[] args){
            helloWorld HW = new helloWorld();
            HW.test();
        }       
    }

    class helloWorld {

        // Define the variable and type
        arrayLess resultSet;

        public void test(){

            resultSet = new arrayLess();

            resultSet.add("test",new arrayLess());

            resultSet.add(5,"Does this work?");

            resultSet.get("test").add("new","value");

            Console.WriteLine(resultSet.get("test").get("new"));

            Console.WriteLine(resultSet.get(5));

            foreach(string key in resultSet){
                Console.WriteLine(key);
            }
        }   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect what you want is (twice):

```
return this.list.Keys.GetEnumerator();
```

---

Or as fully working with some tidying:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
namespace MyApplication
{

    class ArrayLess : IEnumerable<string>
    {

        SortedList<string, dynamic> list = new SortedList<string, dynamic>();

        // Will need to update global list of array_values
        // This will be a proper array
        public void Add(dynamic key, dynamic val)
        {
            list[key.ToString()] = val;
        }

        // Could be int in which case need a list that isn't a sortedList?
        public dynamic this[dynamic key]
        {
            get { return list[key.ToString()]; }
        }

        public IEnumerator<string> GetEnumerator()
        {
            return this.list.Keys.GetEnumerator();
        }

        IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        {
            return GetEnumerator();
        }
    }

    static class Launcher
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            HelloWorld HW = new HelloWorld();
            HW.Test();
        }
    }

    class HelloWorld
    {

        // Define the variable and type
        ArrayLess resultSet;

        public void Test()
        {

            resultSet = new ArrayLess
            {
                { "test", new ArrayLess() },

                { 5, "Does this work?" }
            };

            resultSet["test"].Add("new", "value");

            Console.WriteLine(resultSet["test"]["new"]);

            Console.WriteLine(resultSet[5]);

            foreach (string key in resultSet)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(key);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Or with C# 7:

```
class ArrayLess : IEnumerable<string>
{
    SortedList<string, dynamic> list = new SortedList<string, dynamic>();
    public void Add(dynamic key, dynamic val) => list[key.ToString()] = val;
    public dynamic this[dynamic key] => list[key.ToString()];
    public IEnumerator<string> GetEnumerator() => list.Keys.GetEnumerator();
    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() => GetEnumerator();
}
```

Comment: where does that go sorry?

Comment: @UKUser35 in `IEnumerator<string> IEnumerable<string>.GetEnumerator()` and `IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()`

Comment: @UKUser35 note that the top of your class should also say `: IEnumerable<string>`, not `: IEnumerable`

Comment: Fab! Did try a few things and will mark it as the answer shortly!

Comment: @UKUser35 as minor things, there are a *range* of things that aren't really ... great ... in the code posted; I've tidied up a few of them in an edit. Note in particular naming conventions and the use of indexers, and the public default `GetEnumerator()` and re-use. Personally I hate the use of `dynamic` as an indexer key, but that's up to you. If you have C# 7, it could be a lot prettier, too.

Comment: Thank you for going way beyond!! I also like the this[] function as you can see what I was trying to achieve :o) That way accessing the values will be much easier. I come from a PHP background so am trying to get my head around the C# versions.

Comment: @UKUser35 note you can *also* write an indexer `set` in place of the `Add` - which would be more representative of what happens here. Basically, it comes down to what should happen with duplicate keys. Most people in .NET would expect `foo.Add("abc", 123); foo.Add("abc", 456");` to *fail* (duplicate key), but would expect `foo["abc"] = 123; foo["abc"] = 456;` *to succeed*, retaining the final value. In your case, your `Add` method acts like the second scenario, retaining the final value.